# Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT HDMI no audio?

Tags: sound, nvidia, xorg, pulseaudio

I can't get audio working using a HDMI cable with my Nvidia GeForce 8600 GT card.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge HDMI audio features were added in the Geforce 9xxx series. Prior cards normally only support picture via HDMI

Answer (score 0):

the fact is that is really simple: the graphic card isn't a sound card, so the solution is connect the spdif motherboard's/soundcard's connector to the nvidia's connector spdif in and select spdif in audio output in sound preferences.